# Twig template for custom entity not working

Tags: 8, theming, entities

I created a custom entity (*Representative*) using the Drupal Console `generate:entity:content` command.

The entity works correctly. I added fields, added some content, and I can query this entity.

My problem is that I can't render this entity in a template file, using the following code.

```php
$build = [
  '#theme' => 'representatives',
  '#representative_entity' => $representative
];
```

I get the following error.

> Exception: Object of type Drupal\kelk_representatives\Entity\RepresentativeEntity cannot be
> printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line
> 476 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the entity view builder, to correctly render an entity, like the following code.

```php
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('representatives');
$entity_view = $view_builder->view($representative);

$build = [
  '#theme' => 'representatives',
  '#representative_entity' => $entity_view,
];
```